# what is the use of deployment code in hybris?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

```
<itemtype code="IntegrationSystemCredentials" autocreate="true" generate="true">
                <deployment **table**="IntegrationSystemCredentials" typecode="11000" />
</itemtype>
```

In the above code i have mentioned deployment table and typecode. why we are using both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the above code i have mentioned deployment table and typecode. why
> we are using both?

**The short answer is**: It's because they serve different purposes.

### `deployment table`

Using `deployment table`, you map a database table to the `itemtype`. If you do not mention `deployment table`, the values of the attributes of the `itemtype` will be saved into the `deployment table` of its parent `itemtype`; in other words, in absence of the `deployment table` in the `itemtype` definition, the database table of the patent `itemtype` will be mapped with the `itemtype`.

If you are creating an `itemtype` by extending `GenericItem`, you must declare a `deployment table` (a mechanism to avoid the attributes of the `itemtype` getting saved in `GenericItem` table). However, if you are extending some other `itemtype` e.g. `Product`, you should avoid declaring `deployment table` as much as possible in order to avoid too many joins required during the execution of the Flexible Search Query.

Note that `GenericItem` is the default parent of an `itemtype` i.e. if you do not declare `extends...` in the `itemtype` definition, the `itemtype` will, by default, extend `GenericItem` e.g. the following `itemtype` definition will fail compilation because `DummyItem` extends `GenericItem` by default but there is no `deployment table` mentioned for it.

```
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">
    <itemtypes>
        <itemtype code="DummyItem" autocreate="true">
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="uname" type="java.lang.String">
                    <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true" optional="false"/>
                    <defaultvalue>"Hello"</defaultvalue>
                    <persistence type="property"></persistence>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
    </itemtypes>
</items>
```

### `typecode`

The `typecode` attribute is a unique number to reference the type. The value of the typecode attribute must be a positive integer between `0` and `32767 (2^15-1)` and must be unique throughout your hybris application as it is part of the `PK` generation mechanism as shown below:

```
private static PK createPK_Counter(int typecode, long counter) {
    if (typecode >= 0 && typecode <= 32767) {
        //...
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal typecode : " + typecode + ", allowed range: 0-" + 32767);
    }
}
```

Check [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c6254f086691014b095a08a61d1efed.html) and [this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8c2d4abd866910149207b2f33deaf652.html) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the deployment table in hybris?

Items within SAP Commerce are made persistent by writing values into a database. Within the database, the values are stored in tables. SAP Commerce allows you to explicitly define the database tables where the values of instances of a given type will be written. This can be done by defining the deployment tag.
Like.
`<deployment table="mytype_deployment" typecode="12345" />`

---

> When to define the deployment table?

One should define the deployment table for an item type when

- Your item type doesn't extend any other item type (except GenericItem, which is by default)
- Your item type extend existing item type for which there is no deployment table defined

Read more [Specifying a Deployment for Platform Types](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/2005/en-US/8c6254f086691014b095a08a61d1efed.html)